# Zend Model access in singleton class - best approach

Tags: zend-framework, design-patterns, model, singleton

I'm looking for best pattern/approach to access one table data in singleton class (in ZF 1.x). In details:

- I have one singleton class (just like Zend_Date for example) that make for me some basic abstract stuff very detached from application reality.
- In this class, in two points,  I need to access to one db table and I need to make some basic operation on it.

It's not a problem to use my regular ZF models class inside functions of this singleton. It works fine. Now it look like:

```
class My_ZF_Singleton
{
    ...
    public function someFunctionInMySingleton()
    {
        ...
        $oModel = new Model_My_Model_Form_ZF_Application();
        $oModel->letsDoSomeStuffWithDb();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But I feel in my bones that it's not a very good solution, not so glamour as I would like to be. It make my singleton class more attached to application then it should be. I would like to use some other pattern to access this db data then application model class. I would be very thankfull for any clue or better solution - it's not a "hey I'm stuck probem" or "hey I've got an error" - I'm just looking for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understand your question or want the point might be, but I'll try.

In ZF1 the database adapter is typically a singleton already. [Multiple databases maybe connected](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb) to but each will require a unique identification. Typical access to the default adapter setup in the `application.ini` or `Bootstrap.php`:

`$adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();`

a common way to provide access to a single database table and give access to the [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html) api is to build a [DbTable model](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html):

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_TableName extends Zend_DbTable_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'Table_Name' //required if classname does not match table name
    protected $_primary = 'primary_key_column_name'//optional, use if primary key is not 'id'
}
```

You can treat this class as an instance of the default database adapter for a single table (works really well in a mapper). You can also add functions to this class to override or add to the default Zend_Db_Table api.

I hope this at least comes close.